# Hard Drive Not Detected Error When Swapping Drives

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, dell-inspiron, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

I have a Dell Inspiron 660 computer that's running 32 bit windows 10 and the motherboard fried.

I tried putting the hard drive which still works into a Dell optiplex 9020 and tried to start it up, but I got a "Hard Drive Not Detected" error when starting it up.  The reason I wanted to do this is to retain all the users and installed programs that were installed.

All cables were connected properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Basic fact # 1: Do not replace the system/boot disk of the new PC. Connect the drive as a secondary disk and copy any personal data from it. Basic fact #2: As the disk was in a "fried" computer - consider it as being potentially BAD.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The reason I wanted to do it like I said was to retain all the users and installed programs that were installed. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason I wanted to do it like I said was to retain all the users and installed programs that were installed. Is it possible to do this?

The software was adapted to the hardware it was installed on. You might run into problems even if you had an exact copy of the hardware (e.g. MAC address would differ, some copy protections use it).

In attempting this you wold most likely face a humongous task - already one program might have special settings and selected (hardware dependent) files it requires to work; which were taken care of at install time, based on definitions of the software creators.